# Assign DOM.element to module variable before observer runs

Tags: typescript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I have a module written in typescript, and I am trying to avoid using castings on the $ elements.

I would like to declare a module variable, of the adequate type, to hold the DOM references.

However, I can't find the correct place in the element lifecycle to do this. Please see the code below with my current code:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        value: {
            type: Number,
            observer: "valueObserver"
        },
    }
}

ready() {
    // this.element = this.$.id as HTMLInputElement;
    // this will fail .... $ is undefined

    super.ready();

    this.element = this.$.id as HTMLInputElement;
    // this is useless.... the observer has already been called
}

valueObserver() {
    // I am using this:
    (<any>this.$.id).value = this.value;

    // I am trying to use instead:
    this.element.value = this.value;
    // but it will fail, this.element has not been asigned

}
```